# How to log incoming POST requests

Tags: 7

We are seeing a lot of POST requests by bots to /register pages or pages with forms. This is likely an attempt to make an SQL injection.

What's the best way to log the full POST request and see the payload data?

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You may use [HTTP Request Logger module](https://www.drupal.org/project/request_logger).

Comment: Thanks - Any Drupal 7 ideas? This module is Drupal 8 & above.

Answer (score 0):

If you are Nginx, below answer is the easiest way to log POST requests including data being carried.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939382/logging-post-data-from-request-body